# python character counting please help me im a nooob

Tags: python

hi guys having a little trouble with python very new to it im trying to count how many times a certain set of characters appears in one line anyway i can get it to count but it counts 4 ie.

```
a = raw_input('insert pirate bob speak line line 1 - ')
b = raw_input('insert pirate bob speak line line 2 - ')
c = raw_input('insert pirate bob speak line line 3 - ')
```

im trying to get t to count how many times there is a rr in a sentence but only if a double appears problem is when i launch the full code with the neccesary input of **1.yarrrr harrr**
me hearties
**and a bottle of rrrrum** 
**it counts the amout of double rs i just want to know how many are sentences contain the double r**

Comment: Show how you're trying to count the occurrences of `rr`. Also, how many occurrences does `'rrrr'` have - 2 or 3?

Comment: Show us your code so we can give you details on where you get wrong. The idea is to use loop.

Comment: where is your looping part there? or the part that counts the letter r?

Answer (score 1):

If you want one single rr to be found per line:

```
import re
myline = 'harrrr!'
matches = re.findall('(rr+)',myline)
if matches: 
    print "exactly",len(matches)," rr was found"
```

Explanation:

To learn more about regular expressions, type
    help(re)

This particular regular expression says:
search for all groups in a line, containing two or more 'r's

If you want to search for rr-s but not for rrrs, use:

```
re.findall('(?:[^|[^r])(rr)(?:[^r]|$)', 'harrrarrr')
```

Which is slightly more difficult (search for all those 'rr's, who are either preceded by a character which isn't r or the line starts there, and are followed by either a character which isn't r, or the line ends there, whilst not caring about these following and preceding characters)

In general, you can improve your "control flow" by:

```
import re
while True: #forever or at least until break-[up], you know, love-style forever;)
    line = raw_input("Howdy? ")
    if line: # if the user actually typed in something
        matches = re.findall('(rr+)',line)
        if matches: 
            print "exactly",len(matches)," rr was found"
        else:
            print "you'rrre NOT a pirrate!"
    else:
        break #quit
```